# Magento 2 Get URL from Where order is placed in Observer

Tags: multistore, url, multi-website, magento-2.2.5

After order status change in observer I am getting data of the order.

Now I want to get the URL of the site from where order is placed.

Like if main store then - www.example.com

if french store view then - www.example.com/fr

Please help me with this.

Comment: the order has a storeid which is the store where the order was created.
you can get the storecode with the storemanager

Answer (score 0):

```
   public $_storeManager;
  public function __construct(
      \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       .....
    ) {
       ...
  $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
    }


    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
```